# How to Prevent TD from ending up on a new line?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am dynamically creating a table through Javascript and I DO want the table to continue off the right side of the page. Doing this manually lets the table continue off, but once I feed this into a `for` loop the `<td>`s wrap into a second line in the rendered HTML, creating two or more table rows when they reach the end of the page.

```html
<div id="panelindex" style="overflow:scroll;text-align:center;">
  <table border="0">
    <tr></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

This is inside a table of its own (no style formatting). Then the Javascript:

```js
var q = Math.floor((1/numpanels)*500);
 if(q>50) q=50;
 panelindex.innerHTML = "<table border='0'><tr>"
 for(i=0; i<numpanels; i=i+1)
 {
  panelindex.innerHTML = panelindex.innerHTML + "<td><div id='panel" + i + "' onclick='jumppage(" + i + ")' style='float:left;text-align:center;margin:8px;border-width:3;border-color:white;border-style:none;'><a href='#" + i + "'><img src='thumbnails.php?image=blowem" + zeroFill(i,2) + ".gif&GIF&tw=128&th=128&quality=" + q + "'>\n" + 
        "<br />" + i + "</a></div></td>\n";
 }
 panelindex.innerHTML = panelindex.innerHTML + "</tr></table>"
```

You may notice that there is a `<div>` in the `<td>` and that is so I can apply a border marking the `panel`. Without the `<div>` it seems I cannot do that, and there are some other undesired effects. Any ideas what I can do so that all the `<td>`s end up on one line rather than split to a new line?

Example of what I want: http://edwardleuf.org/comics/jwb/009-conmet

What is happening: https://jsfiddle.net/w4uh0a3j/7/

Click the `Show` link.

Comment: provide a fiddle mate?

Comment: When you say the `<td>` elements end up on a new line, do you mean they wrap into a second line in the rendered HTML, creating two or more table rows, or do you mean that in the DOM created by the JavaScript they wrap into a second line? Or in the HTML?

Comment: @David Thomas The first, they create more rows.

Comment: @Siddharth Couldn't think of how to make the fiddle, so I provided links to what I want and what became.

Comment: Linking to your own site is problematic, given that there's no guarantee your site will remain, that you won't reorganise or that you won't deliberately or otherwise delete the relevant page. Any of which would make the question somewhat nonsensical. Please, at the very least, post the relevant "*[MCVE]*" code in your question (and then, if necessary, *we* can create our own reproduction). Also: where is `numpanels` defined, and from where does `q` originate?

Comment: I don't understand why the snippets are needed here. Any arguments for/agains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`innerHTML` does not hold the string value you assign to it.

It parses the value as HTML, creates a DOM from it, inserts it into the document and then, when you read it back, it converts that DOM back into HTML.

This means that the string you assign is subject to *error recovery* and *normalisation*. In particular, the end tags you omitted are fixed.

```js
panelindex.innerHTML = "<table border='0'><tr>"
console.log(panelindex.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="panelindex" style="overflow:scroll;text-align:center;">
  <table border="0"><tr>

  </tr></table>
</div>
```

So when you start appending more data to it:

> ```
> panelindex.innerHTML = panelindex.innerHTML + "<td>etc etc
> ```

You end up with:

```
<table border="0"><tbody><tr></tr></tbody></table><td>etc etc
```

---

Store your data in a regular variable. Only assign it to `.innerHTML` once you have the complete HTML finished.

A better approach then that would be to forget about trying to build HTML by mashing strings together (which is error prone, especially once you start dealing with characters that need escaping in HTML) and use DOM (`createElement`, `appendChild`, etc) instead.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK,here is fixed html and js code. It seems like innerHTML fixes missing closing  when updating html before all the code is building the rest of innerHTML. This code works :

```
<div id="panelindex" style="overflow:scroll;text-align:center;">

</div>
```

and js code :

```
var numpanels = 100;


var q = Math.floor((1/numpanels)*500);
  if(q>50) q=50;
  panelindex.innerHTML = "<table border='0'><tr>";
  var html = "<table border='0'><tr>";
  for(i=0; i<numpanels; i=i+1) {
    html += "<td><div id='panel" + i + "' onclick='jumppage(" + i + ")' style='float:left;text-align:center;margin:8px;border-width:3;border-color:white;border-style:none;'><a href='#" + i + "'><img src='thumbnails.php?image=blowem" +  ".gif&GIF&tw=128&th=128&quality=" + q + "'>\n" +
            "<br />" + i + "</a></div></td>";
  }
  html += "</tr></table>";
  document.getElementById("panelindex").innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: panelindex.innerHTML = "<table border='0'><tr>"; returns panelindex.innerHTML = "<table border='0'><tr></tr></table>"; and this part of the code is unnecessary.